# update an array into mysql table

Tags: php, arrays

I need to update an array into mysql table.

this is my array

```
[cat2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 48
                    [2] => 49
                    [3] => 46
                )
```

and I want my output as 34,48,49,46 to move into a table called shops and column called category. This is code I written, $shop['cat2'] contains the array i posted above. Please help me. This code is keep only 34 in all fields of column category

```
foreach ($shop['cat2'] as $k => $v) {
    $query = "UPDATE shops SET categories2=$v";
    mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by **move into a table**?

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause to update only one row. That also implies that you need to pull the ids or something from `shops` to use in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I want 34,48,49,46 to move into the first field of column "category",table "shops"

Comment: I think you have to be more explicit. As @MichaelBerkowski mention, you need a WHERE clause to update only one row. Do you want to update the first row of table "shops" and place "34,48,49,46" into field "categories2" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to apply each of these array elements to one row of your `category` column, you will need to first fetch the a unique id from the `shops` table, and loop over it, using that unique identifier value in the update query's `WHERE` clause:

We'll call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` inside the `foreach()` loop to pull one row per one array element. This assumes you have a column `shops.id` which is the unique identifier per shop.

```
// If `id` is not the unique id per shop, substitute the correct column
$rowids = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM shops ORDER BY id");
if  ($rowids) {
  // Loop over your array, and do one update per array elem
  foreach ($cat2 as $cat) {
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowids);
     $id = row['id'];
     // Your values are ints, so no need to quote and escape.
     // If you do use other string values, be sure to mysql_real_escape_string() them and single-quote
     $upd = mysql_query("UPDATE shops SET category = $cat WHERE id = $id");
     // Report error on this iteration
     if (!$upd)  {
        echo "error updating $id" . mysql_error();
     }
  }
}
else {
   echo "Couldn't get row ids. " . mysql_error(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function: `implode(",", $shop['cat2'])`

You might also want to look into [Foreign Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). When using a foreign key you can use a `join` SQL statement to retrieve data from multiple columns. When storing the categories as one field, like in your example, this is not possible.

You would need a new table for that: `ShopCategory` with columns: `ShopID` and `CategoryID`, these columns would have a foreign key relation to your `Shop` and `Category` tables respectively.

As Michael Berkowski already pointed out in the comments, if you do not use a `where` clause, this SQL statement will update the Category for ALL your shops!

`$query = "UPDATE shops SET categories2='".implode(",", $shop['cat2'])."' WHERE id=".$shop;`

Comment: I want 34,48,49,46 to move into the first field of column "category",table "shops"